# Concentrated styles on :before content

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a list with titles of varying length defined in my `li` tag's `:before` pseudo-element `content` property. The contents of the `li` tags themselves are of varying length as well.

Due to the varying lengths, of the titles most specifically, I have used the various `display: table` properties to keep the content aligned. Some of the relevant bits are below, [click here for a full sample](http://jsfiddle.net/j40dusbh/).

```
ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 0 2px;
}

li {
    display: table-row;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li:before {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

> **A NOTE:** Using the `width` property on the `:before` pseudo-element, rather than the `display: table` method, was initially proposed as a solution to line up the content, but the varying lengths of the titles steered us away from that direction so that the title column could be as narrow or wide as the content allowed, not based on a fixed metric.

The idea was then raised to have a background on just the title, extending from the content, like so:

[image: Option 1]

Or even something like this, less preferred, but may offer some canonical benefit to the community if there is a solution to both:

[image]

Just putting a `background-color` on the `:before` makes the background extend the full height of the `li`'s actual content.

We had some luck using `position: absolute` on the `:before` pseudo-element, but then we are back to setting fixed widths to position the content relative to the title, which we were attempting to avoid from the get go.

### So...

#### 1. Is there a way to accomplish this using the `ul`/`li` structure?

#### 2. If not, what are my options? Go to a 2 column floating div layout that then gives me greater control over the styles of the title?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or Codepen showing your full code?

Comment: Apologies, skimmed right over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some combination of `float` and `table-cell`, it's achievable.

Scenario 1:

```css
ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 0 2px;
}

li {
    display: table-row;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li:before {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}

.li1:before {
    content: "I AM PRETTY LONG";
}

.li2:before {
    content: "SHORT";
}

.li3:before {
    content: "MEDIUM LEN";
}

div {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: #ddd;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="li1"><div>Nunc egestas purus vel dui lacinia imperdiet. Nam gravida maximus purus, in ornare turpis pretium at. Suspendisse potenti. Donec condimentum ornare pharetra.</div></li>
    <li class="li2"><div>Praesent imperdiet non arcu pellentesque condimentum.</div></li>
    <li class="li3"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam iaculis condimentum odio, et lobortis metus congue vitae. Nam tellus dolor, consequat eget tellus eu, congue congue felis. Donec eget ipsum commodo, porttitor libero eu, dignissim ligula. Proin vel porta lorem. Vivamus varius risus ac venenatis efficitur. Quisque sit amet tellus sed neque tincidunt pharetra. </div></li>
</ul>
```

Scenario 2:

```css
ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 0 2px;
}

li {
    display: table-row;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li:before {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: auto;
    float:right;
}

.li1:before {
    content: "I AM PRETTY LONG";
}

.li2:before {
    content: "SHORT";
}

.li3:before {
    content: "MEDIUM LEN";
}

div {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: #ddd;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="li1"><div>Nunc egestas purus vel dui lacinia imperdiet. Nam gravida maximus purus, in ornare turpis pretium at. Suspendisse potenti. Donec condimentum ornare pharetra.</div></li>
    <li class="li2"><div>Praesent imperdiet non arcu pellentesque condimentum.</div></li>
    <li class="li3"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam iaculis condimentum odio, et lobortis metus congue vitae. Nam tellus dolor, consequat eget tellus eu, congue congue felis. Donec eget ipsum commodo, porttitor libero eu, dignissim ligula. Proin vel porta lorem. Vivamus varius risus ac venenatis efficitur. Quisque sit amet tellus sed neque tincidunt pharetra. </div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` on the `<ul>`, `<li>` and inner elements respectively will accomplish this. This has the added benefit of storing  the titles in the HTML instead of the CSS.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3><span>A Really Long Title Here</span></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tractatos erroribus conceptam an sed. Inani dicant graeci id duo, vero perfecto maluisset ut eos. Agam veri ubique ne mei, ferri perpetua prodesset duo an, nam quas everti commune te. At justo dicant similique vel.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><span>A Medium Title</span></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tractatos erroribus conceptam an sed. Inani dicant graeci id duo, vero perfecto maluisset ut eos..</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><span>Title<span></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tractatos erroribus conceptam an sed.</p>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    display:table;
}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    clear:both;
    display:table-row;
}

li > h3 {
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    white-space:nowrap !important;
}

li > h3 > span {
    background-color:lightgray;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding-right:0.5em;
}

li > p {

    display:table-cell;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Full [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/8yLqpudy/).

Comment: If there was a button for a close second, I would have hit it. This solution actually just started a bit of an argument over here actually because I love the solution of getting the title out of the CSS like that, but we have other styles more in line with the other solution, so we have opted for that. Stache on!

Comment: Cool, I wasn't sure if you were including the titles in the `:before` because you thought it would help with structure, or if it was part of the problem.